# Marking items as unpublished via Core Service

Tags: 2013-sp1, core-service

I have a requirement to mark one Publication as unpublished to all publication types/targets.

As I see it I have a few options

1. Unpublish each item, from each target it is published to using

> client.UnPublishAsync(new[] { itemId }, unpubInstruction, new[] {
>   targetId }, PublishPriority.Low, readOptions);

2. Run a database script (not ideal and not supported)
3. Find alternative to the SDL Web 8 (CoreService201501) function

> client.RemovePublishStates(publicationId, targetTypeIdOrPurpose)

Does anyone know if there is an equivalent to option 3 in Tridion 2013 SP1 (CoreService2013)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. I think `RemovePublishStates` was added in Web 8 to support backup/restoration and subsequent synchronisation between the CM and broker databases. 2013 SP1's API just allows you to decommission entire targets, so it's probably option 1 for you in this case.

Comment: I can't decommission an entire target, as it is just one publication that I need to remove publish state for

Comment: It looks like David has answered your question. So you *could* decommission, but then you'd have to publish the rest again, which reduces it to a theoretical-only option. That leaves you with option 1. However, you might also consider first setting up a replacement publication target, selectively publishing things as you desire, and then switching over to that, allowing you to decommission the original.

Comment: Answer edited... I meant to specify "Option 1" as being the one for you but omitted the 1!

Comment: Option 1 it is. I have 300 other websites, so unpublishing one is better than re-publishing 300 :) Thanks!