# Remove Publish States in Tridion 2011

Tags: 2011, core-service, unpublishing

Similar to [Marking items as unpublished via Core Service](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15988/marking-items-as-unpublished-via-core-service/15989)

We have an old Tridion 2011 system that we're working to decommission. We can't just turn it off as there is one publication that is still being maintained from it.  So that we can cleanly export the database for just this remaining publication to migrate it to a newer Tridion CMS, we want to decommission all of the other publications in the CMS.

All those publications still have many hundreds of pages showing as being published and because the deployment infrastructure is long gone, any unpublish commands simply fail.  So we need to be able to programmatically set the publish state to unpublished (Web 8's `RemovePublishStates()` would be ideal here) or somehow re-enable the unpublish process with some kind of stub to return a success in place of the missing deployment infrastructure.

Does anyone know of any way of doing either of these?

Comment: TDSE/COM has APIs for this, something along the lines of object.SetPublishState? (sorry can't do the search now, but maybe this points you in the right direction)

Comment: I couldn't find anything about a SetPublishState, plenty on retrieving the current publish state and the info surrounding where published to, who by etc. But not on setting the publish state itself.  I have found a partial resolution with regard to a kind of stubb - see below.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a means of stubbing the Publication Target to allow us to unpublish manually:  The remaining active Publication does have a working deployer attached, so updating the Publication Targets with the details associated with the active deployer means we are able to unpublish from the dormant Publications.  It's a manual process that's going to take some time but it is working.